# Knockoutjs password binding with autofill not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, passwords, knockout.js, viewmodel

Got a binding setup in a form with fields user/password. But when user use the remember password in Firefox the bindings don't get updated and the viewModel properties are empty.

Anyway to force the bindings from Element to viewModel?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that shows us the problem?  Then we can test it ourselves in Firefox to see what is going on.

Comment: Here is the link for fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qaiseriftikhar/F7znv/

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in Knockout and an issue has been raised on [github about it](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/648).